# Why does the syntax for using regular expressions that works in the "Exerciser" app not work in jsonata4java?

Tags: java, regex, jsonata

I am attempting to use jsonata4java using the $match operator and a regular expression in a predicate.

The jsonata code was tested successfully on the JSonata Exerciser application but fails in my java test with error messages that appear to come from antlr (the lexer/parser).  The Exerciser was used with identical inputs.

Things tried:
1) Upgrading to the latest version of jsonata4java (1.0.5).
2) Various ways to escape certain characters (shot in the dark)
3) simplifying the expression
4) using the lambda style in a predicate (tin ~> /regex/) instead of match
5) stepping through some generated parsing code

```
    public void test() {
        try {
            Expressions expr = null;
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode jsonObj = null;
                String json = "{\"id\":\"1234\"}";
                String expression = "$$[$match(id, /1234/)].id";
//              String expression = "$$.id";
                System.out.println("Expression: " + expression);
                jsonObj = mapper.readTree(json);
                expr = Expressions.parse(expression);
                JsonNode jsonResult = expr.evaluate(jsonObj);
                System.out.println("" + mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(jsonResult));
        }
        catch(Throwable th) {
            System.out.println(th.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I expected this code to just display the 'id' attribute, '1234'.  Instead it throws an exception on executing Expressions.parse(expression).  The text of the error messages is:

```
Expression: $$[$match(id, /1234/)].id

line 1:2 at [@1,2:2='[',<16>,1:2]: missing '.' at '[',
line 1:14 at [@6,14:14='/',<29>,1:14]: no viable alternative at input '$match(id,/', 
line 1:14 at [@6,14:14='/',<29>,1:14]: extraneous input '/' expecting {'(', 
'true', 'false', STRING, 'null', '[', '{', '$', '$$', NUMBER, 'function', '-', '$each', '$sift', '$reduce', '$filter', '$map', VAR_ID, ID}, line 1:20 at [@9,20:20=')',<4>,1:20]: no viable alternative at input '1234/)'
```

Hey, I haven't posted here in a while, thanks for the help.

Comment: Also, as a control, I tested with the commented out expression that doesn't contain the match/regex code and the simplified expression worked as expected.

Comment: Looks like the regex hasn't been implemented in the Java version yet - https://github.com/IBM/JSONata4Java#current-limitations

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I appreciate your help.